# Drop down validation valid don't show the drop down

Tags: html, css

Hi i got some problem i realized with my `dropdown`

[image]

As the green field valid appear but however the `dropdown` menu is gone due to my css i have make it remove the tick which remove the background also ?

Here my code for this line

```
<style>
.was-validated .custom-select:valid {
    background-image: none;
}
</style>

<div class="col">
    <label for="select-price-mode" class="col-form-label">Price Mode</label> 
        <select class="custom-select custom-select-sm col-10" id="select-price-mode"  required>
            <option selected disabled value="">Select ....</option>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please select a valid price mode.
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone know even through is valid it still show the `dropdown` menu ?

Comment: add one to more options

Comment: what u mean add one to more options 
my option is call from database which i not showing here

Comment: remove CSS and check it

Comment: is fine i decide to remove that css for it and create my own separate id for it seems to be working better as i expected

Answer (score 0):

Solved i decide to reuse different class id